# How to Install Cassandra in a Local Ubuntu System

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

How to install cassandra on my local ubuntu machine , I installed cassandra in local machine using sudo apt-get cassandra , but the system freezes when i starts cassandra . I have also set 128M heap memory ,but it does't work

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"? What do you see in the cassandra logs? What happens to system resources? A heap size of 1GB would be a good starting point for initial experimenting - usually more for a production machine.

Comment: @DNA  When i start with my current hardware configuration 2 GB RAM ,Intel core2 duo 2.2Ghz , the system stop responding(freeze :) ) and i have to hard reset the PC to continue . This is not a production machine .

Answer (score 2):

There is an official package from Apache Cassandra up to date. http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging. Then you have to be careful about your system, Cassandra uses an needs a minimun of memory and cpu. I recommend you to read these pages:

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/PerformanceTuning

Comment: thanks . I have used the same documentation for installation purpose and i able to successfully install Cassandra , but after a few seconds the the system stops responding ( may be due to low memory) . Is there any way to set cassandra memory usage to a 512MB level or so ?